Why does the Dunn's test in online calculator rejects the null hypothesis while my manual computations cannot reject it?
In my own manual calculations of the Dunn's Test in google sheet, using the formula from a YouTube video, I managed to calculate the same Test Statistic as the online calculator.
However, using the critical value table from the same YouTube video (k=3, a=0.05), I failed to reject the hypothesis for the first pair of data (2.34<2.394) while the results of the online calculator successful rejects the null hypothesis for the first pair. With regards to the second and third pair, I receive the same decisions about the null hypothesis as the online calculator but we seem to disagree on the first pair.
You can see the results of the online calculator's Dunn's test in the image below: 
Their critical values seem to be higher than mine (9.38) but they were able to reject the null hypothesis successfully. How did this happen? Why do they successfully reject the null hypothesis while I fail to do it, even when we have same test statistic?
If you scroll down the online calculator after calculation, it says that "The R code below will produce the same results:"
if(!"MultNonParam" %in% installed.packages()){install.packages("MultNonParam")}
library(MultNonParam)
if(!"dunn.test" %in% installed.packages()){install.packages("dunn.test")}
library(dunn.test)
x1 <- c(14,24,19,14,12,6,14,13,14,25,16,14,12,12,9)
x2 <- c(19,20,30,15,15,21,19,9,20,12,22,22,17,21,25)
x3 <- c(11,29,13,18,14,4,2,19,9,13,21,8,16,16,11)
list1=list(x1,x2,x3)
kruskal.test(list1)
dunn.test(list1)
nreps <- c(15,15,15)
shifts <- c(0,0.3,0.6)
kwpower(nreps,shifts,'normal')

